# String translation for esc_html__() when registering string

Tags: translation, plugin-polylang

I am trying to translate the string 'Home' in wordpress that is registered as an esc_html__().
This is the code registering the themes functions.php:

```
if(!function_exists('gem_breadcrumbs')) {
function gem_breadcrumbs($new = false)
{
    $text['home'] = esc_html__('Home', 'thegem'); }}
/* there many more strings in the function but I only need to  translate 'Home'
```

To register the string I am using polylang (but it could be anything not specific to polylang) and the documentation refers to registering a simple string `_e()` using the following:

```
pll_register_string('breadcrumb', 'Home', 'thegem','true');
```

The string translation appears in the polyang plugin, but does not get translated on the front end.
I believe it has to do with the esc_html__() in the theme functions.php, I also tried this:

```
pll_register_string('breadcrumbs', esc_html__('Home'), 'thegem', 'true');
```

But it did not work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: polylang is offtopic here, as well as other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support questions. However, your first code block contains a PHP syntax error, for some reason there is a closing `)` after `'Home'` before the textdomain. You should ask this in a polylang community

Comment: There are hundreds of open polylang questions. I would say this is a bit of a grey area in terms of it being'off-topic' as the WPML/polylang plugins are so widely used and also Translations are going to be wordpress core by 2024 so at that point everyone will need to be converting from WMPL/Polyang and therefor not be off-topic.

Comment: Unfortunately moderation here is not omnipresent so things will slip through, but that doesn't mean it is on topic. It's also possible to ask a question that mentions polylang but isn't about polylang. The differentiator is do you need Polylang knowledge to answer this? If yes then it is offtopic. If Polylang is purely circumstantial and not essential to the question then no

Comment: And to clarify, localisation APIs such as `esc_html__` or `__` are not off-topic, they are WordPress core APIs, and that is not why your question is off-topic. It's because you are asking how to register it with Polylang, and that is a Polylang dev support question, Currently there are only 74 tags in that tag and not all of them are strictly asking about the polylang plugin, but eitherway "but they're doing it too" is not a defence to bypass the rules and scope

Comment: There... it's not specific to polylang, purely coincidental.

Comment: You're using polylang to register the string via `pll_register_string` that's a Polylang API, that is offtopic here. The very concept of registering a string is from Polylang. If your question is truly not Polylang specific then the canonical answer is: _"WordPress has no concept of registering localisation strings at runtime, WordPress loads i18n strings from mo/po files and if a localised version of the string given to `__(` exists it's used, if it isn't then it is not, no registration exists. Registration is unique to 3rd party plugins such as Polylang/QTranslate/etc"_

Comment: I'm going to lock the comments as this is becoming unproductive and disingenuous. It's clear that you need Polylang help, and that Polylang is a fundamental part of this question. If you want to make your case you should open a question on the meta stack, the comments are not the place to try and change the rules. This stack is not a place to ask for help with Polylang.